# How do I rotate an ImageDrawing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to draw an image which consists of multiple other images. And some of that images are needed to be rotated. I am using ImageDrawing and DrawingGroup

I've found RotateTransform class but it can't be applied to ImageDrawing, only to DrawingGroup.

```
private void RedrawAquarium(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    aquarium.Iterate();

    DrawingGroup aquariumImages = new DrawingGroup();

    ImageDrawing background = new ImageDrawing();
    background.Rect = new Rect(aquarium.Size);
    background.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(aquarium.BackgroundImageUri);
    aquariumImages.Children.Add(background);

    foreach (var fish in aquarium.Fishes)
    {
        ImageDrawing fishImage = new ImageDrawing();
        fishImage.Rect = new Rect(fish.Value.Position, fish.Value.Size);
        fishImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(fish.Value.TextureUri);
        aquariumImages.Children.Add(fishImage);
    }

    DrawingImage drawingImageSource = new DrawingImage(aquariumImages);
    drawingImageSource.Freeze();
    BackgroundImage.Source = drawingImageSource;
}
```

Should I use something instead of ImageDrawing class?

Comment: You could put a collection of Image elements in a Canvas. Each Image might be transformed by its RenderTransform property.

Comment: @Clemens And how do I locate them on a canvas and set their size?

Comment: Use the SetLeft and SetTop methods of the Canvas class and set the Width and Height of the Image element. You could also awake the fishes to life by animating their positions and orientations :-)

Comment: You don't necessarily need to set their positions by Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. The RenderTransform can also include a translation to the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your ImageDrawing in a DrawingGroup and rotate it. The children of a DrawingGroup can be other DrawingGroup items.

I am not an expert, but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagedrawing?view=netframework-4.7.2) explains that ImageDrawing are indeed interesting for performance point of view (freeze possibility) but provide less features than Image.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need simple rotations, this should work:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(fish.Value.TextureUri);
bitmap.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate90;
```

For more complex rotations the answer below should suffice:

```
aquariumImages.Children.Add(new DrawingGroup() { Children = { fishImage }, Transform = new RotateTransform(45)});
```

(Implementation of matoouse's answer)

I have confirmed this does indeed work:
[VS screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PorLI.png)

Comment: No, I need more than simple rotations